# Prevent Xamarin from auto converting System.DateTime to NSDate?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xcode, xamarin

We have a property where we set the CoreData field of type NSDate.  We want to prevent any developer from passing in a System.DateTime to this property so Xamarin does not auto-convert it from System.DateTime to NSDate.  Is there any way of throwing an exception to prevent this from happening?

The reason is that if you pass a System.DateTime with a DateTimeKind "Unspecified" you will get an unexpected result.  We need to prevent this from happening.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea (I'm not entirely sure it'll work though):

Create a new class MyCustomDate, and add implicit operators to/from NSDate. Change the type of your property to be MyCustomDate. I believe the compiler will not allow DateTime to be assigned to this property (it will not go through 2 implicit conversions (DateTime -> NSDate -> MyCustomDate)), so you'll get a compiler error everywhere you assign a DateTime to your property, while assigning NSDate still works.